# How does 形容詞+かる work in Classical Japanese?

Tags: conjugations, i-adjectives, classical-japanese, auxiliaries

I remember reading previously that かる could not be used attributively(1), but that does raise the question: For what else could a 連体形 have been used in the first place?
Was it simply an alternate form of ～き in its zero-nominalisation?
Was it placed where neither an adjectival 連体形 nor the 終止形 would fit, like in ～と and ～可し?
Was it utilised as an emphasised 終止形, similarly to forms of the 連体形 in other constructions?

(1) I have finally [found something of its like](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/difference-between-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%96%e3%82%8b-and-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%ac), was the answerer simply wrong on this subject?

Comment: I think what kind conjugation you should apply on 形容詞 depends on what grammar you are using. For example, if you want to attach らむ , べからず, べし, etc to 形容詞, you need to conjugate it to 連体形. Disclaimer: I just started learning Kobun so I might be wrong.

Comment: After googling for a while, I found a page worth checking out: https://people.ucalgary.ca/~xyang/kobun/3-3-4.htm

Answer (score 7):

### Your main question

> How does 形容詞+かる work in Classical Japanese?

In basic terms, the conjugation charts in the Japanese Wikipedia article at [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/形容詞#古典日本語の形容詞の活用](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E#%E5%8F%A4%E5%85%B8%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) are quite useful.  Reproduced here:

#### Conjugations

The so-called ク活用 or "*-ku* conjugation" is for adjectives that (in modern Japanese) end in just ～い, such as よい or さむい.  Meanwhile, the シク活用 or "*-shiku* conjugation" is for adjectives that (in modern Japanese) end in ～しい, such as あたらしい or さびしい.

| Conjugation | ク活用 Basic | ク活用 Fused with *aru* | シク活用 Basic | シク活用 Fused with *aru* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **未然形【みぜんけい】 Irrealis (hasn't happened yet)** | ～く | ～から | ～しく | ～しから |
| **連用形【れんようけい】 Continuative (*-masu* stem)** | ～く | ～かり | ～しく | ～しかり |
| **終止形【しゅうしけい】 Terminal (standalone)** | ～し | - | ～し | - |
| **連体形【れんたいけい】 Attributive (adjectival)** | ～き | ～かる | ～しき | ～しかる |
| **已然形【いぜんけい】 Realis (as if it's happened)** | ～けれ | - | ～しけれ | - |
| **命令形【めいれいけい】 Imperative (command)** | - | ～かれ | - | ～しかれ |

### Your comment

> I remember reading previously that かる could not be used attributively...

I'm not sure where that might have come from.  As you can see in the table above, the ～かる or ～しかる form is indeed the 連体形【れんたいけい】 or "attributive form", and this is used attributively in historical texts.  Granted, the "basic" attributive form ending in ～き or ～しき appears to be more common for regular usage of an adjective to modify a noun, but we can find instances of ～かる directly modifying a noun, as in [this text](https://books.google.com/books?id=W-IVPv_pRB0C&pg=PT102&dq=%22%E9%AB%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE9prfkN31AhU1GTQIHVD9CVo4FBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22%E9%AB%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%22&f=false) from 1949:

> 御堂より**高かる**空に五山浮き松風の鳴る広業寺かな

### Follow-on questions

> For what else could a 連体形 have been used in the first place?

[Jimmy Yang's](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/41067/) comment on your question links through to [a page](https://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Exyang/kobun/3-3-4.htm) that does a good job of providing a nutshell explanation of what the 連体形【れんたいけい】 was used for.  There is also more [here at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E5%BD%A2-662204) and [here at the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E5%BD%A2).  (Sadly, the English Wikipedia article section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E5%BD%A2) is a bit of a mess, so please only read that with a grain of salt.)

Briefly, in English, the 連体形【れんたいけい】 or "attributive form" of either a verb or adjective could be used to:

- modify a noun or noun phrase, basically just being an adjective.
- act as a noun itself -- this may have evolved by an elision (omission) of an abstract noun like こと ("fact, thing"), which the attributive may have originally modified.
- serve as an attributive, but coming after the thing it modifies, in a special kind of Old Japanese grammatical construction called 係【かか】り結【むす】び.

> Was [the *-karu* form of the *rentaikei*] simply an alternate form of ～き in its zero-nominalisation?

I'm not familiar with the term "zero-nominalisation", so I cannot answer you here.

> Was [the *-karu* form of the *rentaikei*] placed where neither an adjectival 連体形 nor the 終止形 would fit, like in ～と and ～可し?

I'm not aware of any cases where と requires the ～かる form of an adjective.

Note that the *-karu* ending is a fusion of regular adverbial ending ～く + the attributive form of Old and Classical Japanese copula ("to be" verb) あり.  I wonder if the requirement of this form for certain 助動詞【じょどうし】, such as べし or らむ, might be because the 助動詞 itself requires a verb -- which is provided with the ある in ～かる, but not in the "basic" attributive ～き ending.

> Was [the *-karu* form of the *rentaikei*] utilised as an emphasised 終止形, similarly to forms of the 連体形 in other constructions?

I have no idea what other *"forms of the 連体形 in other constructions"* you are referring to, so again I cannot answer you here.

Comment: Do let me clarify what I have unintentionally obfuscated:
On the matter of its capability of modifying nouns, I saw its use condemned as incorrect in one forum post, and of the two sources I can find now, [one](https://www.kotenbunpou.com/%E7%94%A8%E8%A8%80/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E-1-%E3%82%AF%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%82%B7%E3%82%AF%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8/) makes no specific mention of かる, other than appending a べし to it in example, and [the other](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1021756025), presumably not as reliable, omits any mention of adnominal use entirely.

Comment: By 'zero-nominalisation', I was referring to the 連体形's use as a noun in of itself without overt suffixing like with こと and の. As for the last part on your post, from what I know, the 連体形 over the development of Middle Japanese came to be able to act as a 終止形, eventually overtaking it entirely. Would one be able to use かる in that same predicative fashion?

Comment: @John, re: attributive use, ～かる is definitely less common than ～き.  Considering the built-in ある, there may be a nuance there that escapes me, which would influence word choice.  Re: _using ～かる predicatively_, so far as I've seen, the ～かる ending seems to carry a strong sense of Classical Japanese-ness. Since ある could not be used predicatively in Classical Japanese, and あり was used that way instead, it looks to me like ～かる is similarly not found in any predicative role, and only ～かり appears that way.